# Modify WYSIWYG or TinyMCE configurations in magento 2

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

Within the editor it seems html is validated so that multiple elements cannot be placed within a tags. I want to allow markup like below:

```
<a href="#"><h2>Category</h2><img src="logo.png" /><p>Some text...</p></a>
```

This however always ends up like so:

```
<a href="#"><h2>Category</h2></a><img src="logo.png" /><p>Some text...</p>
```

I have seen posts about this however am unsure how to modify **valid_elements** 
or **valid_child_elements** within magento 2.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597219/how-to-configure-tinymce-to-allow-block-level-elements-inside-anchor-a-tag

There is also this but this applies to Magento 1 :

https://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/overcoming-magentos-wysiwyg-part-2-customizing-tinymce-settings/

So far have tried looking at **module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/form/element.phtml** and **lib/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js** as this is the only place i could see configs like this but had no luck.

How can i override these settings with Magento 2?

Comment: starting point js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

Comment: Is that the Magento 1 path?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry, should have said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check my question on 
[TinyMCE Community](https://community.tinymce.com/communityQuestion?id=90661000000Iix7AAC).

**There is the answer:**
TinyMCE views anchor links as an inline element and will not allow block elements to be placed inside of them.  This is a limitation of the current TinyMCE object model.  As a workaround, you could use a span inside the anchor tag and style the text as needed based on the span.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same problem, solved it by follow way.

Navigate to `Dashboard > store > settings > Configuration > general > content management > WYSIWYG Options > Enable WYSIWYG Editor`, choose **Disabled by Default**.

After setting, you could still use WYSIWYG Editor in catalog content, but it is **not default now,** it will not affect your html codes in page or block unless you click the <kbd>Show/Hide Editor</kbd> button.

Comment: I solved my problems with tinymce in Magento this way too. ;-)

Comment: THANK YOU +1000

Comment: Helped me too. thanks